# Chrome causing 404's ending with "/cache/[hex-string]/"?

Tags: url, cache, 404, google-chrome

Since the last weeks we see many 404's on our sites caused by Chrome adding `/cache/[hex-string]/` to the current page URL.

The hex strings we have seen are:

- e9c5ecc3f9d7fa1291240700c8da0728
- 1d292296547f895c613a210468b705b7
- 408cfdf76534ee8f14657ac884946ef2
- 9b0771373b319ba4f132b9447c7060a4
- b8cd4270356f296f1c5627aa88d43349

If you search for these strings you get matches from different sites, but they are most likely auto-generated (`/search/cache/e9c5ecc3f9d7fa1291240700c8da0728/` for example).

Is this a known issue with Chrome (or an extension)?

Comment: Are you running through any firewall or similar? I have not see anything like that, so i wonder if its caused by your local network setup?

Comment: Website traffic comes via nginx and then to Apache (Python), but that did not change. The hex strings are also not commits from our git repo. Because we only see them from Chrome, and the Google index contains similar sites (growing number each day), I suspect this is related to a recent version of Chrome or an extension.

Comment: Same problem here! You can add d31fee2103d18244b731b1623650ec2e to the list of strings. I would like to add that it is a select group of users that trigger these errors but always in chrome. I have seen chrome 18 and 19 so it's not a specific version. Also, there are a lot of search results. Most of them will be auto-generated, but a lot of them show traffic reports and such, so there are probably a lot of other sites who get these requests. https://www.google.com/search?q=cache/d31fee2103d18244b731b1623650ec2e

Comment: This has been reported as a bug: http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-bugs/browse_thread/thread/f7bf05553bf6ad0c - on pages "with a 'share  
button' like share on facebook/twitter/addthis."

Comment: You should add your comment as an answer @Soz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like a bug in a chrome extension:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132059

It is marked as "won't fix" by chrome developers, as it depends on the extension owners.

Answer (score 2):

I feel this is answered in the comments by Soz

*This has been reported as a bug: groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-bugs/… - on pages "with a 'share button' like share on facebook/twitter/addthis." – Soz Jun 11 at 20:43*